# Json Provider fails with Illegal characters in path

Tags: f#-data

I am using the FSharp Json Provider.
I am deploying to an Azure Web App.
When I deploy to Dev, it works fine.
When I deploy to TEST, it fails with the following message:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Illegal
>   characters in path.",
>   "ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":"    at
>   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String
>   fullPath)\r\n    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare
>   share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
>   secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath,
>   Boolean checkHost)\r\n    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)\r\n    at
>   FSharp.Data.Runtime.IO.asyncRead@237-5.Invoke(Unit unitVar) in
>   C:\Git\FSharp.Data\src\CommonRuntime\IO.fs:line 237\r\n

The type is genertated by

```
type Entities = JsonProvider<"./someDir/Sample.json">
```

and the error is generated here

```
let response = Entities.Load(currentUri)
```

I tried removing the file and in-line the sample json when I generate the type, but that also fails with the same error code.

Anyone have any ideas?  Is it the currentUri?  It is the same across all environments

Comment: Very mysterious... Well, okay, what's the difference between environments? Can you try yet another, the third environment? Can you insert in your code `let a = currentUri`, `let b = currentUri.Trim(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())`, `let c = currentUri.Trim(Path.GetInvalidPathChars())` and print `a, b, c` somewhere, e.g. to App Insights?

Comment: I gave up and instead of the TP, used a web client and the newtonsoft deserizalizer

Answer (score 0):

I let it go and went with web client and newtonsoft.